# Show/Hide divs in JQuery for items in a ForLoop

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I am attempting to change my DisplayFor to an EditorFor when the checkbox is clicked, I'm not sure if theres a better way that I could've done this change but if you have any suggestions I'm open to them. But anyways, with the way I did it, it is only doing the JQuery for the first part in my ForLoop and I am not sure how to make it to apply to all the parts in the list. As  right now it is displaying both the displayFor and the editorFor.

I have rows that are generated like this

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < item.IHP.Count; i++)
   {
        Part part = db.Parts.Find(Model.Parts[i].ID);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].ID)
   
        <tr class="tr_clone">

        <td>
            @part.PartIDLink
        </td>
                               
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
        </td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold">
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" class="part-class" data-partId="@(part.ID)" checked>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="AllTxt">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
            </div>
            <div class="editQty">
                     @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Parts[i].Qty)
            </div>
        </td>
        @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType, new { name = "partRadio" })
            </td>
        }

        </tr>
```

My Jquery code looks like this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //iterate through checkboxs
            $(" input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                //if checkbox is checked
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    //show alltext div
                    $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".AllTxt").show();
                    //hide other div
                    $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".editQty").hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".editQty").show();
                    $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".AllTxt").hide();
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {

                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
                //getting closest tr
                var selector = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    // remove cloned row
                    $('#' + Id + 'clone').remove();

                    selector.find(".AllTxt").show();
                    selector.find(".editQty").hide();
                }
                else {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find('td');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                    $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
                    $clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", (i, n) => n + 'clone');
                    $clone.attr('id', (Id) + "clone");
                    selector.find(".AllTxt").hide();
                    selector.find(".editQty").show();
                }

            });
        });

    </script>
```

But it only does this for the the first part in the ForLoop. How can I make it so that it applies it to every part in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given `id` to your div instead use `class` here and whenever any checkbox is checked use `$(this).closest('.tr_clone')` and using this we can hide or show div of required `tr` only .

**Demo Code** ( I have removed some code and added dummy data to it ) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //iterate through checkboxs
  $(" input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    //if checkox is checked
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      //show alltext div
      $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".AllTxt").hide();
      //hide other div
      $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".editQty").show();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".editQty").hide();
      $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find(".AllTxt").show();
    }
  });

  $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function() {

    let Id = $(this).attr('id');
    let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
    //getting closest tr
    var selector = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    //if checkbox is checked
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
      ///find divand show or hide
      selector.find(".AllTxt").show();
      selector.find(".editQty").hide();
    } else {
      selector.find(".AllTxt").hide();
      selector.find(".editQty").show();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tr_clone">

    <td>
      @part.PartIDLink
    </td>

    <td>
      PartName
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
      QtyInItem
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="part-class" data-partId="1" checked>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!---added class instead of id-->
      <div class="AllTxt">
        SomethingAll
      </div>
      <div class="editQty">
        SomethingQty
      </div>
    </td>


  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_clone">

    <td>
      @part.PartIDLink
    </td>

    <td>
      PartName
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
      QtyInItem
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="part-class" data-partId="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="AllTxt">
        SomethingAll
      </div>
      <div class="editQty">
        SomethingQty
      </div>
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank-you. Just curious if you know how this would work with cloned rows? I have updated my question to show you what I mean. But I want the cloned rows to start off as editQty and not AllTxt

Comment: What is `part-class` here? Sorry I don't know asp.net :) but if that part is there in your provided code can you point it out ?

Comment: It's just the class name for the checkbox